# How to convert a number answer to a string of asterisks

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Popcorn 
{

   public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{
   String farm ; 
   double acre = 0;
   int jar = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.print("Input the file name with .txt extention : "); // for the user to input the file name with .txt extesion.

    File fileName = new File(input.nextLine());// Gets the File Name
while(!fileName.exists()) {       // It will ask the user to enter the file  name again if it is not in directory.
    // Prompts for input file name

    System.out.print("The file is not in this directory. Please re-enter the file name: "); 
    fileName = new File(input.nextLine()); //Gets the File Name
    input = new Scanner (System.in);  // Constructs File object 
 }
```

This is the input file:

```
   Orville's Acres, 114.8  43801
   Hoffman's Hills, 77.2  36229
   Jiffy Quick Farm, 89.4  24812
   Jolly Good Plantation,  183.2  104570
```

This is how it should output:

```
Popcorn Co-op
      Production in Hundreds
      of Pint Jars per Acre
Farm Name                 1   2   3   4   5   6
                     ---|---|---|---|---|---|
Orville's Acres         ****************|
Hoffman's Hills         ****************#***
Jiffy Quick Farm        ************    |
Jolly Good Plantation   ****************#***
Organically Grown Inc.  ************    |
```

This is what I am getting when I run the program:

```
               Popcorn Co-op
                         Production in Hundreds
                         of Pint Jars per Acre
Farm Name                    1   2   3   4   5   6
                      ---|---|---|---|---|---|
Orville's Acres    15
Hoffman's Hills    18
#Jiffy Quick Farm    11
Jolly Good Plantation    22 
#>
```

If anyone could tell me how to convert the numbers that I am getting to the stars I would appreciate it.

Comment: Traditionally, you'll want to use a loop.

Comment: The code you provided will never output what you say it already does. Please update the code with what you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I got you right but might that fix it for you?

```
String str = "";
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStars; i++) {
  str += "*";
}
```

Comment: Where do I add that in?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code, not visible in what you've provided, there should be something that's printing the numbers 15, 18, 11 and 22. Instead of printing them, create a loop that will add the stars, as in the previous answer:

`String str = "";
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStars; i++) {
    str += "*";
}`